# Does Vista and Windows 7 come with the "Bookman Old Style" font?

Tags: cross-browser

Currently I'm generating text using this font server-side, but I've been told Vista and Windows 7 come with this font pre-installed.

True or no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Not true.**

For a list of fonts supplied by default with Windows see this page:

- [Fonts supplied with Windows 7](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/product.aspx?PID=161)
- [Fonts supplied with Windows Vista](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/product.aspx?PID=149)

Or the general [fonts overview page](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/product.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

[Windows Vista Fonts](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/product.aspx?PID=149)

[Windows 7 Fonts](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/product.aspx?PID=161)